# Creation of simple template

Tags: templates

I have been asked to make a simple LaTeX template for a friend of mine. Here is my attempt:

```
\documentclass[
  danish,
  a4paper,
  12pt
]{article}


\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
  hmargin=2.4cm,
  vmargin=3cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{enumitem} Maybe include.
\usepackage{microtype}


\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding=T1}

\setlength\parindent{1em}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}
\setlength\headheight{42.5pt}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-29pt}
\lhead{}
\rhead{\rule{100pt}{38.1424pt}} % Insert logo here via \includegraphics.
\cfoot{\scriptsize Læreruddannelsen i Århus, Trøjborgvej~$82$, $8200$~Aarhus~N, telefon~$87\,55\,30\,00$}


\begin{document}

\vspace*{\baselineskip}
\begin{center}
  \textbf{%
    {\LARGE\MakeUppercase{bacheloropgave}}\\[\baselineskip]
    Emenvalg og -begrundelse\\
    (2007-uddannelsen)\\
  }
  {\scriptsize Jf. Bekendtgørelse om uddannelsen til professionsbachelor som lærer i folkeskolen, $\S~10$}
\end{center}
\vspace{4ex}

\noindent\textbf{Fag}\\
Something\\[1.2\baselineskip]
\textbf{Emne}\\
Something\\[1.2\baselineskip]
\textbf{Emnebegrundelse}\\
Something
\vspace{4ex}

\noindent\textbf{Navn}\\
Something\\[1.2\baselineskip]
\textbf{Studienummer} \hspace{5em}    \textbf{Stamhold}\\
$123\,456$            \hspace{9.01em} $12.34$\\[1.2\baselineskip]
\textbf{Underskrift}

\end{document}
```

My main problem is that when I use `\hspace{5em}` at the bottom of the document, I don't know how to automatically vertically align "Stamhold" and "12.34"; the `9.01em` is found by eye-balling.

If there are any other comments to the template, please let me know.

P.S. The width of the `\rule` in the header is set precisely to give the same headheight as the logo does.

Comment: I would use `memoir` as the base instead. Get lots of freebies in the mix. Wouldn't it be better to use a table for those data instead of messing with `\hspace`?

Comment: @daleif I've never learned `memoir`, unfortunately, so I would like to stick to `article`. Regarding the table use of a table: Your suggestion makes sense. (If I can make you create an answer, that would be great.)

Comment: Learn it, there are so many twists and turns you have to go through with `article`, `report` and `book`.

Comment: This this just for the front page? Or for the entire project?

Comment: I do not understand the adding negative space to the `\textheight`

Comment: @daleif It is a one-page document; tt is a sheet of papir for signing a "contract" as far as I understand it.

Comment: @daleif The negative headheight comes from egreg's answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34042/15874).

Comment: I would just ignore the logo to begin with and place it globally afterwards using something like `eso-pic`, then one does not have to deal with *strange* things like that.

Comment: @daleif Okay; I'll have a look at that. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is this to be filled in by hand or by your friend through an editor? Because then I would use `environ` to provide better interfaces for the user.

Comment: @daleif By an editor. If you will show what you have in minds regarding an improved template, I will be happy to see it. `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the allignment.

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}l @{\hspace{5em}}   l}
\textbf{Studienummer}  &   \textbf{Stamhold}\\
$123\,456$            & $12.34$
\end{tabular}
```

By very fast take on it, not including the logo. I'd also like to make the headline better, but out of time for today.

```
\documentclass[
  danish,
  a4paper,
  12pt
]{memoir}


\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setlrmarginsandblock{2.4cm}*1
\setulmarginsandblock{3.5cm}{4cm}* 

\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic,picture,calc}
\usepackage{microtype}

\AddToShipoutPicture{
  \put(\paperwidth-\foremargin,\paperheight-2.5cm){\llap{\rule{100pt}{38.1424pt}}}
}

\usepackage{environ,etoolbox}

\newcommand\Generator[1]{
  \NewEnviron{#1}{\subsubsection*{#1}\BODY}}

\Generator{Fag}
\Generator{Emne}
\Generator{Emnebegrundelse}
\Generator{Navn}
\Generator{Underskrift}

\setlength\aftersubsubsecskip{1sp}

\newenvironment{Studieinfo}{
  \par\vskip-\beforesubsubsecskip % negative length
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l @{\hspace{5em}}   l}
    \textbf{Studienummer}  &   \textbf{Stamhold}\\
  }{
  \end{tabular}
}

\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding=T1}

\makepagestyle{st} 
\makeoddfoot{st}{}{\scriptsize Læreruddannelsen i Århus,
  Trøjborgvej~82, 8200~Aarhus~N, telefon~87\,55\,30\,00}{}

\pagestyle{st}

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \bfseries
  {\LARGE\MakeUppercase{bacheloropgave}} % don't want \LARGE to mess
                                % with line spacing

  \vspace{1em}

  \normalsize
  Emenvalg og -begrundelse

  (2007-uddannelsen)

  \medskip

  \normalfont \scriptsize 
  Jf. Bekendtgørelse om uddannelsen til professionsbachelor som lærer
  i folkeskolen, \S~10
\end{center}

\vspace{3em}


\begin{Fag}
  Skrev noget her
\end{Fag}

\begin{Emne}
  Skrev noget her
\end{Emne}

\begin{Emnebegrundelse}
  Skriv noget her
\end{Emnebegrundelse}

\begin{Navn}
  Skriv dit navn her
\end{Navn}

\begin{Studieinfo}
  % Studienummer & Stamhold
  123\,456    & 12.34
\end{Studieinfo}

\begin{Underskrift}
  % just used to add a headline
\end{Underskrift}
\end{document}
```

---

Addition: Add `picute` and `calc`. I'd like no to care about the width of the gfx, so we wrap it in `\llap` and thus only have to figure out where the lower right corner of the gfx should be placed, whic is up to the OP.

`\paperwidth-\foremargin` is the right edge of the text block

`\paperheight-3cm` is some arbitrary length from the top of the paper.

```
\usepackage{eso-pic,picture,calc}

\AddToShipoutPicture{
  \put(\paperwidth-\foremargin,\paperheight-3cm){\llap{\rule{100pt}{38.1424pt}}}
}
```

Comment: This looks really good! I'm looking forward to a 'better' headline. (Not that I think what you have now is bad.)

Comment: Regarding the picture, I got `\AddToShipoutPicture{\put(416,750){\includegraphics{VIA-UC-logo}}}` by eye-balling but isn't there a better way to place the picture at the right side of the header? (The picture can be downloaded from http://gupl.dk/703750/.)

Comment: That depends. Where do they want it. Do you have some template you're trying to replicate? Plus if you know your way around the memoir layout you can have latex calculate the position for you

Comment: The picture should be right-flushed in the header.

Comment: How do you know where the header should be? Again, if you have some kind of Master to work from, please post all details. This adding dribbles... If you add the picture package and perhaps call then you can use normal lengths as coordinates. Then I'd use \llap and \outermargin

Comment: The original template can be downloaded from http://gupl.dk/703777/.

Comment: Thank you for the update! (You talked about a better headline; have you added that? I'm just asking because I cannot find it.)

Comment: It was added to the full update of the code. I'd rather not see users being exposed to using \\ in plain text, they often get the wrong idea and we have to spend hours unlearning their strange ideas

Comment: Thanks a lot, daleif! Are you 'done' with the MWE or do you feel the need for further improvements? `:)` A single question: Shouldn't the `\vspace` length be with unit `ex`? I thought `em` was for horizontal spacing.

Comment: Ex is AFAIK the height if the x in the current font. Em is the current font size. So Em kan be used for both. As Em matches the font size it is just very useful as a general unit. The template can alway be made better, but for a one of...

Comment: I see. Thank you. If you want to improving the template, feel free to do it (and post it here, please). `:)`