# Title page header also leaves space on other pages.

Tags: fancyhdr

When trying to put a logo at the top of my title page, it somehow leaves space for the logo on all other pages as well. This means all text is shifted down, while this should only happen on the title page.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}

    \thispagestyle{fancy}
    \setlength\headheight{122pt}
    \addtolength{\textheight}{-122pt}
    \chead{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{TiUlogo.jpg}}

    \vspace*{3cm}

    \huge
    \textbf{Some text}
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

This gives the logo at top of title page only, with the text shifted down so it does not overlap. But on other pages, the text still seems to be shifted down, without me wanting to do so. I used \thispagestyle to make it work only on the title page. I do get a warning that headheight is too small, should be at least 121.33118, but the strange thing is, I already put it to 122. Any help?

Comment: see if `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` after the titlepage helps.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than play with the page dimensions (which carry through the document unless reset), one could follow the lead of Ulrike at this answer, [Graphics/logo in headers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34040/graphics-logo-in-headers/34068#34068), and merely use the optional arguments of `\raisebox` to set the effective graphic dimensions to zero.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}

    \thispagestyle{fancy}
    \chead{\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{%
      \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth,height=2cm]{TiUlogo.jpg}}}
    \vspace*{3cm}

    \huge
    \textbf{Some text}
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]