# How to: Header on every page, with figures!

Tags: graphics, header-footer

I'm writing a document to my college and it requires a header on every page with two logos and some text, as shown below:

[image]

Here are the images:

[image]

[image]

Any ideas on how to do it? I have tried with the package `fancyhdr`, but I just couldn't make the figures work with it. The document class is article.

Please note that this header must be on the top of every page of the document and not on just particular ones.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34040/24974

Comment: Is it two-sided? Is thee text just under the horizontal line part of the header?

Comment: @Bernard It's one sided and the text below the horizontal line is not part of the header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution, with `geometry` and `titleps`, instead of `fancyhdr`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\SetTracking[no ligatures={f}]{encoding=*}{40}
\usepackage{graphicx, array}
\usepackage[headheight=136pt, top=6.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{lipsum} %
\newpagestyle{myheader}{%
\sethead{\includegraphics{htFCS}}{\sffamily\large\raisebox{6ex}{\parbox{6cm}{\centering\lsstyle%
  Centro Universitário da FEI\\[3ex]Projeto de Iniciação Científica}}}{\scalebox{0.75}{\includegraphics{aNF04}}}
\headrule}
\pagestyle{myheader}

\begin{document}

\section{Section One}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It worked very well. The only remaining problem is that the header doesnt show up on `tittlepage`, `abstract` and the table of contents page.

Comment: Which class of document do you have?

Comment: Its an article. I managed to add the  header to the title page and abstract by using `\thispagestyle{myheader}`
Dont know how to do it with the TOC however.

Comment: Oops, nevermind. Problem solved! Thank you very much!

Comment: That's what I was going to answer for this case. Fine! Often the page style in title pages is set to `plain`.

Comment: I just realized after modifying the pagestyle, that the page numbers are gone! How do I add them back in such a way that they do not appear on the first 3 pages?

Comment: Where do  you want to add them? Bottom centred? Also, the first three pages correspond to what?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39044/discussion-between-c-b-jose-and-bernard).

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit in a rush so I will comment the code later.

I hope this can inspire 
you.

[image: header with logos]

### The Code

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[left=4cm,top=6cm,right=3cm,bottom=3cm,headheight=5cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.2pt}
\lhead{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node [anchor=west,inner sep=0] (logoLEFT) at (current page header area.west) {\includegraphics[height=3cm]{logoSX}};   
\node [anchor=east,inner sep=0] (logoRIGHT) at (current page header area.east) {\includegraphics[height=3.5cm]{logoDX}};  
\coordinate (tt) at ($(logoLEFT.east)!.5!(logoRIGHT.west)$);
\node [above=.5cm,font=\bfseries\Large] at (tt) {Centro Universitário da FEI};
\node [below=.5cm,font=\bfseries\Large] at (tt) {Projeto de Iniciação Científica};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
Type your document as usual!
\newpage
\section{Second section}
Type your document as usual!
\end{document}
```